# Drupal cache issue while we use same domain using different theme for mobile and desktop

Tags: caching

I'm new to drupal and I have an issue with drupal7 caching system. I have enabled drupal cache and it will refresh the cache for every 1 hour. I have couple of themes for my site. One for normal desktop users and another one for mobile users. Now the problem is once I open the site from mobile for the next 1hour the mobile theme is caught by drupal cache and the same is sent to desktop request also. Even though I open the site from desktop it self I can view the pages of mobile theme only. After clearing cache manually or after 1 hour I can view the desktop theme.

Note: I'm using mobile_switch for theme switching.

Comment: This is why responsive design is so important. You can't use agressive page caching if you need to show different versions of the same page to arbitrary, anonymous users depending on a per-request variable

Comment: Well, sorry to say that but you made a classic error. If you are switching themes in php code, and then use caching to omit most of php execution, it is bound to fail, **by design**. And it is a [known issue for year and a half](https://drupal.org/node/1591210) or more. But most important: **We see what bothers you, but what is your question?** We don't fix module bugs here, you know, and now your question looks like that's what you expect.